# Import ranges with getRangeList

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I am new in Google scripts so I have one question.

I found a script that helps me to import data from one central document to other documents (sheets). Script works good when I try to import one range of data and than other separately, but it doesn't work when I try to import  multiple ranges with `getRangeList`. I have tried with `setValues()` but it doesn't work. `setValues()` works only when I use `getRange()`.

Can someone help me with my problem?

Comment: What framework/tool you're using? Please specify in tags

Comment: I added tag. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can adapt this [utility function](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/135911/20335), which joins a list of ranges into one big range, so that the combined update of each range can be applied in bulk.